# Is $\frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (x-x_{i})f(x)dx$ different from $\frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (x_{i+1}-x)f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm currently studying the Piecewise Linear Rayleigh-Ritz method in *Numerical Analysis* by Burden (10th Edition), and I'm facing with these two integrals.

$$Q_{5,i} = \frac{1}{h_{i-1}} \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (x-x_{i-1})f(x)dx $$
$$Q_{6,i} = \frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (x_{i+1}-x)f(x)dx $$
Is it true or false that $Q_{5,i+1} = Q_{6,i}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ Q_{5,i+1} = Q_{6,i}$$

$$\iff \frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (x-x_i)f(x)\mathrm{d}x  = \frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (x_{i+1}-x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x $$

$$\iff \frac{1}{h_{i}} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (2x-x_i-x_{i+1}) f(x) \mathrm{d}x=0$$

$$\iff \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} (2x-x_i-x_{i+1}) f(x) \mathrm{d}x=0 $$

And in the general case it is false, let's take $f :x \mapsto x$, $x_i =0$ and $x_{i+1}=1$ then you have:

$$\int_{0}^{1} (2x-0-1) x \,\mathrm{d}x  = \dfrac{1}{6} \neq 0$$